# Uncaught TypeError when running npm start with my react three fiber project

Tags: reactjs, package.json, react-three-fiber

I keep getting an error when running my 3D product configurator project with npm start. When i try it with npm run build then the error is gone and everything works without any problems. But with npm start the development process would be must easier so i would like to have that error fixed by can't find any solution for it.

This is what the error looks like:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIk3C.png)

I think it has something to do with the package.json file but i am not sure. This is what my code looks like:

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "3d-configurator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "3d configurator",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start"
  },
  "author": "wdv",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^26.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.80.9",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "three": "^0.156.0"
  }
}
```

I want it to work with npm start so that i would see the changes i make directly on the screen. With npm run build it takes a bit too long for that.